# How to get calendar events by date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nscalendar

I am inserting data in my device calendar by this code.

i want those events by date.

if i pass date and i want to get event name.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to use EventKit/EventKitUI framework. 
please refer code provided by Apple : [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) This sample shows how to use EventKit and EventKitUI frameworks to access and edit calendar data in the Calendar database.